# Why does the IsMouseOver trigger not work for a Grid ColumnDefinition?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ismouseover, columndefinition

**Goal:**
I'm trying to create an accordion-style `Grid`, using only a couple of columns (`ColumnDefinition`).

**Expected behavior:**
The `ColumnDefinition` `Width` should increase to `2*` when the mouse cursor is above the column. It should return to `1*` when it's not.

[Expected behaviour, e.g. for the cursor above the red column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYunM.png)

**Actual results:**
The columns do not react to the cursor above them. The widths remain fixed, i.e. `1*`.

---

**What I've tried:**

- Testing the exact same `Style` for the `Grid` element itself (only switching the `Grid` `Background` property in place of the `ColumnDefinition` `Width`, but still being triggered by the same `IsMouseOver`, it works fine.) (Added something related to this in the 1st edit below.)
- Adding the `Background="Transparent"` property to the `Grid` element, in case that the cursor has nothing to "stick" to. (Of course there is no `Background` property for the `ColumnDefinition` to try the same.)
- Limiting the height of the `Rectangles` to see if the trigger happens over them or in the same column but above/below them. Removing the `Rectangles` alltoghether (however then it's impossible to even see the triggering effect).
- Adding/removing the initial `Setter Property="Width" Value="1*"` (above the `Style.Triggers` tag)
- Explicitly referring to the `Style` with its `x:Key` property.
- Tried on WPF Core .NET 5.0. and WPF .NET Framework 4.7.2.

---

I know that there are other ways to make this work (leaving the `Column` width as `Auto` and working with the `Widths` of `Rectangles`, or maybe changing the `Column` `Widths` [through events in the code-behind](https://pastebin.com/pbaqsPee)). But using the row/column star unit of width and a single style seems to be the perfect way, eliminating the need to write any additional logic. And I really can't see why this would not work. I'm guessing that right now the cursor is not recognized at all over the column area, but I'm having trouble understanding why.

---

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition" x:Key="ColumnAccordionStyle">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="1*"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="1*"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2*"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Style="{StaticResource ColumnAccordionStyle}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Style="{StaticResource ColumnAccordionStyle}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Style="{StaticResource ColumnAccordionStyle}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Style="{StaticResource ColumnAccordionStyle}"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Column="3"/>
    </Grid>
```

EDIT:

- The `IsMouseOver` for let's say `Grid`, is inherited from the `UIElement` class ([UIElement Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)), but for the `ColumnDefinition` it is inherited from `ContentElement` class ([ContentElement Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.contentelement?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)).
- Added my [temporary workaround solution](https://pastebin.com/pbaqsPee), in case it helps someone...

Comment: `IsMouseOver` is a property of class `UIElement`.  `ColumnDefinition` is not a `UIElement`.   In fact it's not in the UI at all, technically.  You need to pick something in the actual user interface, apply a style to that..  LIke some UI control that lives in the Grid column

Comment: @Joe you are correct. However, if you look at the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.columndefinition?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)  for `ColumnDefinition` you can see that it has a `IsMouseOver` property, and, as you say, it does not inherit it from `UIElement`, but it does from `ContentElement`. And reading about the differences between the two, MS says that "_they share many of the same members and APIs_" and even that "_ContentElement is typically not as restrictive about content as UIElement_".